# Edits on tag wikis counted for Copy Editor?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, tag-wikis

I was cleaning up and expanding the blurbs on several tag wikis when I noticed that the edits I'm performing on them seem to count towards my progress on the Copy Editor badge, which explicitly restricts tag edits. Is this a bug? I want to earn this badge properly even if it takes a little longer so I guess I'm asking:

1. Am I correct that tag edits are (incorrectly) counting towards the Copy Editor badge?
2. If so, is there a way to change this and eliminate those edits from my count?

To be clear, I'm not going to stop making helpful edits when I get to the threshold like a badgehound, but as I said, I want to earn it the proper way.

Comment: yeah, i just went from 206 to 207 without any posts so they're for sure counting

Comment: What is not counted I think are pure changes of tags of a question (likely on the grounds that this is a bit minor); I would not see a reason why edits to tag wikis should not count. I don't really know if they count, but I think they should count.

Comment: I see, so 'tag edits' means 'changing tags', not 'editing tag pages.' That would clear it up.

Comment: Good. for the sake of completeness I wrote up an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that there is a bug.

A "tag edit" means changing the tag(s) of a question, *and doing nothing else.* This is not counted towards the badge, presumably as it seems a bit minor.

Editing the description of a tag is not a "tag edit." There is no reason why they would be excluded. From the process or the effort they are also close to an edit of a post, thus this makes sense.